# A variant of vertex labeling problem

Tags: complexity-theory, vertex-labeling

We are given an undirected graph $G(V, E)$, and let $n = |V|$. The task is to find a bijective function $\psi: V \rightarrow \lbrace{1, 2, \dotsc, n \rbrace}$ such that the following objective is minimized: $\sum_{(u, v) \in E} \max(\psi(u), \psi(v))$. I am interested in the complexity of this problem. Note that this problem seems very close to other vertex labeling problems such as the *Linear Arrangement Problem* and *Minimum Sum Vertex Cover Problem [MSCV](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/165237/min-sum-vertex-cover-complexity-proof)*. Any references or hints is most welcome.

I tried the following greedy heuristic.

```
counter <- 0 

list = []

while counter < n

     v <- Vertex with the highest degree in G with ties resolved randomly

     list.append(v)
 
     Remove all edges incident to v from G

     counter <- counter + 1
```

The above natural greedy heuristic however fails to return an optimal solution. To demonstrate consider the following graph with vertices $V = \lbrace{A, B, C, D, E \rbrace}$ and edges $E = \lbrace{ (A, B) , (A, D), (A, E), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D), (C, E) \rbrace}$. If we apply the greedy procedure, then list generated is $[A, C, B, D, E]$, so $\psi(A) = 1, \psi(C) = 2, \dotsc, \psi(E) = 5$. The objective for this labeling is 28, since: cost($A, B$) = $\max(\psi(A), \psi(B))$ = 3, cost($A, D$) = 4, cost($A, E$) = 5, cost($B, C$)= 3, cost($B, D$) = 4, cost($C, D$) = 4, cost($C, E$) = 5.

Consider an alternative labeling where $\psi(A) = 1$, $\psi(B) = 2$, $\psi(D) = 3$, $\psi(C) = 4$, and $\psi(E) = 5$. The cost calculation for this labeling is 26, thereby disproving the optimality of the greedy heuristic mentioned above.

Comment: @Highheath: I tried a similar greedy heuristic, I added those details in the problem description. Unfortunately, it does not yield an optimal solution.

Comment: @Highheath: Your earlier description was fine, however I couldn't formally prove that moving the vertex of minimum degree to the top reduces the objective. Perhaps you can outline one. I recently found that if we replace max in the objective to min, then it reduces to [MSCV](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/165237/min-sum-vertex-cover-complexity-proof) problem, which is NP-Complete. However, the problem I stated here still is open.

Comment: @Highheath: Consider the following counterexample. Let $S_1 = \{a, b, c, d\}$, $S_2 = \{f, g, h, i \}$. Consider a graph with vertices $S_1\cup S_2\cup e$, edges $E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3$. $E_1$ is the set of edges between all pair of vertices in $S_1$. $E_2$ is the set of edges between all pair of vertices in $S_2$ & $E_3 = \{(a, e), (b, e)\}$. Consider a labeling $\phi$ in which the vertices are arranged lexicographically. Note that vertex $e$ has degree 2 while all other vertices have degree $>= 3$. If we relabel the vertices s.t. $e$ is the last vertex, you can check the cost increases.

Comment: To see why cost increases, note that none of the edges in $E_1$ cost more in the new labeling. There are 6 edges in $E_2$, each of whose cost decreases by 1 in the new labeling. The cost of the 2 edges edges in $E_3$ increase by 8 in the new labeling, so overall the cost goes up by 2.

Comment: Okay, right! I was wrong about this, yes. And it's not just because the graph is disconnected either. Then I will delete my comments.