# Min sum vertex cover complexity proof

Tags: complexity-theory, vertex-cover, vertex-labeling

One version of the minimum sum vertex cover [1] is the following problem:

We are given an undirected graph $G(V, E)$, and let $n = |V|$. The task is to find a bijective function $\psi: V \rightarrow \lbrace{1, 2, \dotsc, n \rbrace}$ such that the following objective is minimized: $\sum_{(u, v) \in E} \min(\psi(u), \psi(v))$.

[1] & [2] implicitly claim that the problem is NP-Complete to solve optimally, however they do not point to any references that prove the claim. I could not find a source myself after searching a lot on the internet. Can someone point me to the proof of the problem or provide hints if you happen to know.

References

[1] Gera, R., Horton, S., Rasmussen, C. and Stanica, P., 2006. Results on the min-sum vertex cover problem. Congressus Numerantium, 178, pp.161-172.

[2] Feige, U., Lovász, L. and Tetali, P., 2004. Approximating min sum set cover. Algorithmica, 40, pp.219-234.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken [2](https://tetali.math.gatech.edu/PUBLIS/mssc_final.pdf) proves this in Theorem 14 with the slightly stronger claim: "For some $\epsilon′ > 0$, it is NP-hard to approximate min sum vertex cover within ratios better than $1 + \epsilon′$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments [2](https://tetali.math.gatech.edu/PUBLIS/mssc_final.pdf) proves this in Theorem 14 with the slightly stronger claim: "For some $\epsilon'>0$, it is NP-hard to approximate min sum vertex cover within ratios better than $1+\epsilon'$."